# Android action bar doesn't show

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have set up a custom action bar for an android application. It has 2 buttons (left and  right) and the title (middle).

However I dont understand why it doesn't show up. (I have a small white band instead)

here is my custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/oeo_grey_4"
        >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/actionbar_menu_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:src="@drawable/actionbar_menu_button"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TITLE"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="@color/oeo_grey_2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/actionbar_account_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:src="@drawable/actionbar_account_button"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The piece of code where I set the action bar : It is MenuActionBarActivity.java which extends Activity.
This class is extended by HomepageActivity.java (the Activity in wich I want to display an action bar)

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_menu_button);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    actionBarMenuButton = (ImageView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_menu_button);
    actionBarTitle = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
    actionBarAccountButton = (ImageView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_account_button);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've wrongly set custom view using: `actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_menu_button);`.

You could `inflate` your custom view:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

check out [this tutorial](http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

try in your MainActivity.java$OnCreate

```
getActionBar().show();
```

in your styles.xml

```
<style name="HoloLight" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>
```

in you manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/HoloLight">
```